# Ngrx independent stores

Tags: angular, plugins, ngrx, state-management, infrastructure

I'm currently working on an enterprise application based on a plugin system (the component can be instantiated dynamically many times).

I'm looking for a way to use ngrx for these components to handle different states on each instance.

I found the forFeature function in the ngrx module declaration, but this allows me to distinguish between modules and not between multiple instances of the same component.

Another way should be to use a unique ID for the component instance to identify a portion of the state, but in this way every action, reduction and effect should handle it.

Any other idea?

Update:
this is a stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxdg7e

I want each component to interact only with it's own store slice.
In the example when i press "increment" all the instances counter is incremented becouse they share the same store slice, i want them to be indipendent by each other

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say `forFeature` has anything to do with modules/component, by doing `forFeature('feat', reducer) | forFeature('feat', objOfReducers)`, you're simply adding another **slice** to the state, in this case `feat`.

So if each component represents a slice of the state, but you don't want to wrap each of them inside a module(in order to use `forFeature`), you could try using [`ReducerManager.addReducer`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/reducer_manager.ts#L73-L75):

```js
addReducer(key: string, reducer: ActionReducer<any, any>) {
  this.addReducers({ [key]: reducer });
}
```

Now, another problem may arise, where would you add `ReducerManager.addReducer` in your component, if it will be instantiated multiple times?

I'd say that if the slice of store should disappear when the component is destroyed, you could add `ReducerManager.addReducer` in `ngOnInit`, and `ReducerManager.removeReducer` in `ngOnDestroy`. Otherwise, you can use a global service to keep track of the components which have been instantiated once.

Comment: The problem is that when i instantiate two different components and add the reducer to the store two times these reducers will handle the actions from both the components. I want to have complete different instance of the store

Comment: Can't you have a unique reducer per component(i.e per slice) ?

Comment: I added the reducer using ReducerManager as you suggested in the ngOnInit of the component. Now if i have in the page two instances (A and B) of the same component and i dispatch an action on instance A, this will be handled even by the reducer of instance B.

Comment: Ah, okay. Makes sense. I think because it's the same instance of the same component, they're operating on the same slice. And if that's true, the slice will have the reducer of the most recently added instance. Could you elaborate on `complete different instance` ?

Comment: i mean that the same component is declared in the page two or more times so for each of them i register the reducer but all the reducer handle the same action type

Comment: I'd say that there will be only one reducer, no matter how many instances you're having. So in this case, what would be the expected behavior? I think it would be easier if you could create a StackBlitz.

Comment: My final purpose is that every component instance handle action, selector and recucer on a different portion of the state

Comment: Hi Andrej, i updated the question with a stackblitz

Comment: Thanks for the demo, but I no other idea than to create a unique slice for each component, which implies a different set of actions for each slice reducer. This does not sound like a good solution, though.